# Ajax and the back button stumper

Tags: jquery, ajax

So my site relies heavily on Jquery and `$.post`, essentially there is only an index.php page and all the content is loaded via AJAX request from my php. Now, the history plugins look great, BBQ, history.js, etc but they all seem to utilize the anchor tag which I use non of. I might have gotten away with using one but I have buttons that need different classes and id's so I can't use one class for every button and somehow use `.trigger` to call an event based on the hash in the url. My question is this. Without a complete overhaul of my site because it's basically finished, is there an easy way to implement a back button without an anchor tag?

Sorry if I'm not clear I can try to explain more if needed, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Short answer is no. Back button functionality should have been built into the original spec for the site framework if it was needed.

Comment: That's what I kinda figured, thanks for the response Ryan.

Comment: I think you and I have rather different definitions of "complete overhaul."

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to push a History State to use the back button, I suggest you simply get every single anchor with the proper jquery selector.

```
$('a')
```

It selects every anchor element and will allow you to create those virtual "Addesses", however every bookmark will be broken and nobody will be able to link anything but your homepage.

Comment: _"however every bookmark will be broken and nobody will be able to link anything but your homepage."_ - not necessarily. It's possible to  just run a bit of JavaScript when the page first loads to check the URL for a bookmarkable hash (or equivalent).

Comment: The issue is that if he is pushing history like example.com/virtual/file that does not actually exist when he requests the server for /virtual/file it will not know what to do. He could override the 404 message now that I think about it though.

Comment: What I'm gathering is that you can't easily use AJAX for dynamic content and then just have the correct url display. I guess I can make a page for each click and just use a `$_POST` for menu items that are just informational, but if I don't know the result of the AJAX in some instances how can I have a url still show such as blah.com/product=44